# Stripe Android: Adding card, SourceRetrievalListener callback not called

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I'm trying to add card sources to current customer (ephemeral key fetched and session initialize already). The card is added to the user but the callback `SourceRetrievalListener` is not triggered, so my flow of waiting for the card add result cannot end.

When I again open my activity for card list it fetches the card for which I didn't received the callback.

```
 CustomerSession.getInstance().addCustomerSource(getContext(), token.getId(), token.getType(), new CustomerSession.SourceRetrievalListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSourceRetrieved(@NonNull Source source) {
                        Timber.tag("ADDCARD").d(source.toString());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(int errorCode, @Nullable String errorMessage) {
                        Timber.tag("ADDCARD").w(errorMessage);
                    }
                });
```

I do receive this log value when trying to add the card:

```
D/NativeCrypto: jniThrowException: java/net/SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

Any thing I'm missing here?

here is the link to the issue I opened on github:
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/issues/553

My environment is testing not production.